# Ошибка при создании проекта в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer

Поставил PhP, установил composer, сделал окружение, начинаю создавать проект, и тут ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам текст ошибки:

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Из ошибки понял что нужно какой-то пакет активировать вроде, а какой хз, гуглил, нашел только схожие ошибки, но проблемы другие.
Как можно все это исправить?

Problem 1
- laravel/framework[v8.12.0, ..., 8.x-dev] require league/flysystem ^1.1 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[1.1.0, ..., 1.x-dev].
- league/flysystem[1.1.0, ..., 1.x-dev] require ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension.
- Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^8.12 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v8.12.0, ..., 8.x-dev].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
- C:\php\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Comment: Прочитайте повнимательнее, используйте перевод и вникните в то, что там написано. Разработка ПО тем и отличается от гуманитарных наук, что в нём есть точность, последовательность и логика.

Comment: нужно установить, для используемого php, расширение ext-fileinfo